# Export PowerShell variables in a single line

Tags: variables, powershell, csv

I am writing a basic information-gathering script that we can throw out on AD domains as a GPO-based logon script to collect some basic inventory information. Here is a code sample with a couple of the items we are pulling:

```
$Model = (Get-WmiObject -Class:Win32_ComputerSystem).Model
$Serial = Get-WmiObject Win32_SystemEnclosure | select SerialNumber | findstr /C:"1" /C:"2"
$Hostname = get-content env:computername
```

(Please ignore the pipe to `findstr` for the serial number; this is for a Dell environment.) I would like to write these values to a single row in a CSV file. In batch, this would be as simple as:

```
echo %model%,%serial%,%hostname% >> info.csv
```

And this is the sort of output that I am going for:

```
host1,serial1,model1
host2,serial2,model2
host3,serial3,model3
```

But at best I am able to achieve something like:

```
host1
serial1
model1
host2
serial2
model2
```

I have been playing with this for a while and for some reason I am having a hard time getting these variables exported in a single line. Is there a way to format the output like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the same approach as in batch:

```
echo "$model,$serial,$hostname" >> info.csv
```

Comment: Yes! Exceedingly simple, excellently elegant. Every way I had seen to accomplish this so far was overkill. Kind sir, I thank you (:

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking that you need to use `Add-Content`:

```
Add-Content -Path c:\temp\csv.csv -Value '"$Hostname","$Serial","$Model"'
```

That will make a line in text file with quoted, comma separated stings. You could easily have this in a `ForEach` loop if you are targeting multiple computers.

Answer (score 0):

Just testing with Powershell 10.0.18

The following command is working for writing in a file:

```
$theProcess = (Get-Process TheProcessYouWantToCheck)

while (1) {
    Write-Host $theProcess.name, $theProcess.cpu
    Add-Content -Path C:\folder\output.txt -Value "$($theProcess.name), 
    $($theProcess.cpu)"
    Start-Sleep 1
    Clear-Host
}
```